# AndroidAnnotations access Singleton class object into other class static method

Tags: android, singleton, android-annotations

From MyActivity, call to:

1. MyClass.getInstance();
2. MyClass.doStuff();

...

```
@EBean(scope = EBean.Scope.Singleton)  
public class MyClass {
    @Bean
    MyManager manager;

    public static void doStuff(){   
        manager.show();
        // null pointer exception for the manager  why ? how to access it ?
    }  
     public static MyClass getInstance() {
        if (_instance == null) {
            _instance = new MyClass();
        }
        return  _instance;
    }
}
```

...

```
@EBean(scope = EBean.Scope.Singleton)  
public class MyManager {
    public void show(){     }
}
```

Android annotations access singleton class object into other class static method.  Note : AA version 3.3.1

Comment: I am sorry, but your problem is totally unclear in your question. Please tell us what you are trying to do and what's the problem, that you are coming across while trying to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you are using AA `@EBean` incorrectly. Did you read the [documentation](https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance%20custom%20classes)?

You do not have to write a `getInstance()` method yourself, AA will generate the appropriate method, do the injections in it, and automatically call it when injecting the bean into other components. You got a `NullPointerException` because you created the bean with your own `getInstance()` method, so no AA injections were performed. But actually you are getting a compile error in `doStuff()`, because you are accessing an instance field in a static method... So i assume the `manager` field is static, right? You should not use static fields/methods in singletons, the concept of the singleton is one instance is existing only, so using static fields/methods is redundant and also confusing.

You can fix the problem by either:

- Creating an instance of `MyClass` by calling `MyClass_.getInstance(context)` manually, then use it
- Inject a `MyClass` instance into another component with the `@Bean` annotation and use it from there

Comment: That's good catch for compile time error, actually I want to access the manager object into static method. That was main hurdle. When we instantiate object using "new" keyword, AA do not inject DI/IoC. We have to declare the class member  with annotation like @Bean ... But docs does not say's about the MyClass_.getInstance(context) method. Do you have link to this?

Comment: There is no documentation about `MyClass_.getInstance(context)`, because generally you should never call it. Just inject your beans with `@Bean` and AA will call that method automatically. You should never instantiate enhanced objects with `new` or own factory method.

Comment: BTW, why do you need that field `static`? As i already explained, you should not use that.

Comment: I apologize for not clear with my requirement. public static void doStuff(){ } is static and I want to access manager object which is non-static(data-member of class MyClass ) which is NOT possible. So to access it I need MyClass object. And hence if I create the object of MyClass (using "new" or some other factory methods)it will not instantiate manager object through as per AA(i.e. don't inject  IoC/DI).

Comment: Sorry, but i really do not understand your motives here. Just let the field and methods be non-static, too, and use `@Bean` to inject to object, or if you want, you can get the bean manually with the generated `getInstance_()` method.

Comment: MyClass_.getInstance(context) solved my problem when the class is NOT using AA(@Ebean)